# Insert New Record Before Existing Recordds in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with an existing MS SQL database and ASP.NET web application. An update is needed in a table, but in order to add the new data and have it display correctly in the site, I need to be able to take a series of existing records, essentially "push them down", and then add the new data in the open space created.

Is there a cleaner, more efficient method than by just creating a new record that's a copy of the last related record, and then essentially doing a copy-and-paste for the remaining records until I reach the insertion point? There are quite a few records to move and I'd prefer something that isn't as mind-numbing and potentially error-prone as that.

I know the existing site and database isn't designed optimally for inserting new data into this table unless it's added to the end, but reconfiguring the database and stored procedures is not an option I presently have.

**-- EDIT --**

For additional requested information...

Screen shot of table definition:

[image: Table definition screen shot]

Screen shot of some table data (filtered by TemplateID):

[image]

When looking at the table data, there are a couple other template ID values that bring back a bit more complex data. The issue is that this data needs to maintain this order, which happens to be the order in which it has been entered, since it gets returned and displayed in the shown order. The new data needs to be entered prior to one of these lettered subject headers. Honestly, I think this is not the best way to do this, but I had no hand in the design. It was created by a different company, and mine was hired to handle updates and maintenance after the creators became unpleasant to work with. A different template ID value brings back two levels of headers, which doesn't make my task any easier or alterations much cleaner considering the CS code that calls the stored procedures is completely separated from the code that builds the contents of the pages, and the organizational structure i tough to follow. There are some very poor naming conventions in places.

At any rate, there needs to be an insertion into this group of data under the "A" header value. The same needs to occur with another chunk associated with a different template ID, and there is another main header below the insertion point:

[image]

Comment: What you are describing does not make sense, That is called `order by` and its a presentation issue.

Comment: are you able to supply the table definition and small sample dataset to see if we can work out what you are asking here?  If you can't change the proc to add `order by` there may be other ways.  Copy-paste in SQL Server sounds plain daft but until there is more info, we'd be simply guessing what you are trying to do here.

Comment: By definition a table is an unordered set. As such there is no such thing as inserting in the middle. The insert just appends data to the set. The concept of order is when you retrieve data and for this we use the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Unless you're talking about inserting rows into an in-memory datatable in your asp.net app.   But if that is the case, then this question should be tagged with asp.net, and not sql-server.

Comment: There must already be some kind of sorting implemented, because you cannot rely on the order of records in the table, as per definition of a relational database. Depending on different factors, the resulting order is not deterministic without explicit sorting. I think you should check what defines the current sorting and "hook in" there, e. g. by using a sequence number 1 for the new row and "shifting" (+1) the sequence numbers of the existing rows.